# Need help resolving non-zero exit status 1 submitting project

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to verify the submission of a directory for a school project, but everytime I try to test the submission I get this message:

> "Command '('/Users/{myname}/Documents/Coding/tmp_verify_submission_OHA6GFA/venv/bin/pip', 'install', '-r', '/Users/{myname}/Documents/Coding/tmp_verify_submission_OHA6GFA/requirements.txt')' returned non-zero exit status 1."

There are two files in the directory: main.py and requirements.txt

I believe the problem is with main.py which is code to extract text from a google drive for a stock trading project.

Here is main.py:

```py
import gdown
import json
import os.path

file_exists = os.path.exists('pelosi_stock.json')

url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yBWLq-4xzOTFtVa-HAJTpVu5Y_X9EP18/view?usp=sharing"
output = 'pelosi_stock.json'

if file_exists == False:
    gdown.download(url, output, fuzzy=True, quiet=True)
    with open(output) as file:
        py_dict = json.load(file)
        print(py_dict['message'])
elif file_exists == True:
    pass
```

Here is requirements.txt which is for the libraries the professor should download to make the main.py download:

```
gdown
json
os.path
```

Comment: Are `python`  and `pip` installed on the machine? User permissions can be another potential issue. A non-zero exit code indicates failure, but it is difficult to point out the cause without more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your issue is the `os.path` in your requirements file, if you really needed the `os` package installed you'd have just `os` in there.  That and `json` probably don't need to be in the requirements file since they're part of the standard library (ie they come with installing python)

Try removing at least the `.path` part in `requirements.txt` and I'm sure it will work.

Generally speaking, you install entire packages in python